Python implementation for Price Model - scale-free network growth model for directed graphs
I'm trying to create a scale-free network growing model in networkx in Python. Plenty of resources exist on Github for the Barabassi-Albert Model, but my graph needs to be directed and BA is designed only for undirected graphs.
I understand that the Price Model is effectively the directed equivalent of the BA Model, but I can't find any online resources for how to implement that in Python (preferably nx). Could anyone point me in the right direction?
I've tried to tweak the BA model to account for outbound degrees, but implementation hasn't worked so far:
    deg = G.out_degree(n) ## number of outbound edges from this node
    print('out degree',deg)
    deg_weight = deg / (2 * len(G.edges()))
    print('degree weighting:',deg_weight)
    edge_weight = edges_per_node[pre_node_type] ## weighting by observed connectivity
    adjusted_prob = prob * deg_weight * edge_weight
    n_probs.append(adjusted_prob)
    nodes.append(n)


what is Price Model? What is Barabassi-Albert Model? If you have some resources then you could add links in question (not in comments)

In the source code for the Barabasi-Albert graph generation, they start from an initial star network with m+1 nodes which in the networkx implementation is an undirected network. You can modify this part to generate a directed star graph of m+1 nodes where m edges go out from a central node somewhat like this:
def directed_star_graph(n):
  G = nx.DiGraph()
  for node in range(n):
    G.add_edge(0, node+1)
  return G

Then change the line in the source code
repeated_nodes = [n for n, d in G.degree() for _ in range(d)]

to
repeated_nodes = [n for n, d in G.in_degree() for _ in range(d)]

so that every new node that comes in gets attached to m nodes, thus having the average out-degree constant at m over time, and the attachment is preferential, i.e., proportional to in degrees of the existing nodes.
The initialization does not really matter when you are generating large networks.
